# Pro*C/C -->Java --->pro*c using JNI

Tags: java-native-interface

I have some Pro*C code  and some java method.

end user will invoke Pro*C/C binaries on linux/solaris/aix,
it will make call to Java method
post execution of java method, call should be back to C/Pro*c calling function

Any example/POC.

PS : there are many sample to call Java--->C  but not much reverse.

No C++ please

Answer (score 0):

How's [this example](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/invoke.html)

Comment: djna, much helpful thanks.
Any article where  C global variable set to null/0, call java, java will set those global variable of C, control back to C.

Answer (score 0):

Using JNA it's quite easy to pass in a callback to the Java-code:
https://jna.dev.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Callback.html**strong text**